# php strpos() not checking correctly

Tags: php

I'm facing problem while using strpo(). Let's say the string is "51 Minutes" and I'm checking for "1 Minute" it still returns true as it should not. What is the fix ? I want to search only for 1 Minute.

Code :

```
if (strpos($str, '1 minute') !== false)
{

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: find `" 1 Minute"` :)

Comment: Have you thought about this: the function works as it's supposed to, but the guy in the chair is mistaking how it's used? If you read really carefully, you will notice that `51 Minutes` contains the string `1 Minute`. Logical conclusion - function works, problem in chair.

Comment: Post your code, it's possible that the problem is not strpos but something else in your code, so, post your code.

Comment: Are you using strpos for the right reason? "1 Minute" is a substring of "51 Minutes".

Comment: Yes! What should I use ?

Comment: Your question is about to be locked because you've not posted any code

Comment: Sorry. I have updated the answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are misunderstanding the usage of `strpos`

[strpos()](http://php.net/strpos) returns either false, in the event that the string isnt found, or the numeric position of the first occurrence of the string being looked for. It does not return 'true'.

To get a boolean result, you can test for `not false` like this. (notice the use of `!==` which tries to match value and type.  This avoids 0 giving you a false result).

```
if(strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {
    // do something here
}
```

Also note, that for some annoying reason the 'haystack' and 'needle' are the reverse of many of the other PHP string functions, which makes it easy to make a mistake.

However, as you are trying to find a certain string, and only that certain string, you need to use either a straight comparison, like:

```
if($string == '1 Minute')
```

or use regex to match a complete word with a pattern such as this:

```
$pattern = '/\b1 Minute\b/';
```

this can then be used with preg_match like this:

```
preg_match($pattern, $input_line, $output_array);
```

If youve not used regex before, [this](http://www.phpliveregex.com/) site is very good for helping you create your patterns and even gives you the code line to paste in.

Comment: The problem is `strpos` is matching too much, not that it's returning `false`

Comment: yes I know, I hadnt finished. I hit return by accident.

Comment: Sure, Can I know one thing ? This regex expression will remain same for all other languages to match ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_match()` to find whole words.

The code you're looking for:

```
$string = "Lorem ipsum 51 Minutes on StackOverflow";
$regex = "/\b1 Minute\b/";    

$match = preg_match( $string, $regex );
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\fb\test.php on line 8

Comment: You forgot a closing `/` in your regex

Answer (score 0):

Since someone went the regex overkill route let me offer the simplest route. `strpos` returns the **position** of the string that matched, not just if it matched. So...

```
$str = "1 Minute here";
if(strpos($str, '1 Minute') === 0) {
    echo 'Matched 1 Minute';
}
```

If it's at position 0, then it means the string starts with **1 Minute**. Assuming you don't want to do anything crazy like find all instances of the word, this can suffice. Otherwise, use the regex answer